# Why am I receiving invalid expression in my vue.js template?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am receiving this error in my vue single file component:

```
  Errors compiling template:

  invalid expression: Unexpected token { in

    {{ jobs[0].build_link }}

  Raw expression: v-bind:href="{{ jobs[0].build_link }}"
```

The full line is:

```
 <td :style=tdStyle><a v-bind:href="{{ jobs[0].build_link }}">{{ jobs[0].build_link }}</a></td>
```

jobs is defined in the data method of my component and i can console.log this data without issue.

Also not sure why, but this line works fine with an inline-template vue.js script but throws this error after converting over to a single page component.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have a syntax problem. Please try without curly braces. 
for ex:

```
<td :style=tdStyle><a v-bind:href="jobs[0].build_link">{{ jobs[0].build_link }}</a></td>
```

Hope it works..

Comment: There is a small typo in your `v-bind:href` value. Should be `jobs` and not `obs`.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the curly braces is correct in this case because the v-bind syntax is going to evaluate the expression, but double curly braces will also pre-evaluate it to a string so you end up trying to evaluate a string. So you essentially end up with something like `v-bind:href="https://google.com"`, but `"https://google.com"` is not a variable or expression. Make sense?